# React "interval" has always the same state

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using react 16.10 with typescript.
I have this code:

```
  const [state, setState] = useState<State>({
        test: 1
    });  

    //On component mount we start our interval
    useEffect(() => {
        const timerID = setInterval(timer, 5000); //every 5 seconds

        return function cleanup() {
            //When we leave component we stop the timer
            clearInterval(timerID);
        };
    }, []); 

   function timer() {
        if(state.test === 3){
            //HE WILL NEVER ENTER THIS CODE FUNCTION
        }

        setState({...state, test: 3}); // Next time we should have the value 3, BUT IT HAS NEVER THIS VALUE?!?!
    }

   return (
        <>
     <span>The output is {state.test}</span> //First it is showing 1, after 5 seconds 3. Working great
        </>
    );
```

I am changing the value of test to the number 3 in the interval "timer". setState is working fine. I can see the value in my component, seeing the number switching from 1 to 3.

But in the timer function the value is never changed. It has every time the default value of 1.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add dependency to `useEffect`

```
 //On component mount we start our interval
  useEffect(() => {
      const timerID = setInterval(timer, 5000); //every 5 seconds

      return function cleanup() {
          //When we leave component we stop the timer
          clearInterval(timerID);
      };
  }, [state.test]); // <- here add dependency
```

> Reason

Your effect function is called only once when component is mounted and it stored `timer` functions reference. now when you state changes your `timer function` is also `updated outside` but not `inside of useEffect`.

`useEffect` still uses old reference when `state was 1` so `inside it State always going to be 1` for that `referred timer function`

Now when you pass `state.test` as dependency. when state get changed your effect will updated and it now start using new `timer function` which has new state.

So now, you can have updated state in your `timer function`. and your condition can evaluate correctly.

if any doubts please comment.

Comment: thank you it is working, but is this the best solution? It feels so uncorrect. Let me explain: Every time when the value test changes it runs the cleanup functions, destroys the interval and creates a new one, every time when the value changes. This alone feels not good. This is a minified example, in real I have many setStates, changing not only one value, but many. That would mean I have to set EVERY state I change in the useEffect method [...].

Comment: yes its the correct way. but if it is not fitting to your scenario. best case would be use `class component`. as functional component get complex when they become big. or you can use multiple `useEffect` to make sure which things needed to change at when

Comment: react also stated they are not in mood of deprecating `class components` soon. so use them if you fill something is not correct :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing anything wrong, your `useEffect()` has a completely different value in memory and without knowing this behavior about `useEffect()` you have nothing in there telling `useEffect()` to stop looking at that old value and start looking at the new value. As Hardik wrote, your `useEffect()` is called only once, so you still have that old value that was originally called in there and `useEffect` has no idea that your timer has changed since. It will be referencing that original value forever.

What you can do is completely remove the empty array as the second argument and you will notice the difference in behavior.

Using a direct reference to the variable you are using in your state as suggested by Hardik seems to be the way to go.

So again, `useEffect()` is not being called a second time and as a result, nothing inside it is being ran again so it all in stale reference.

One of the tips the facebook team gives to mitigate this bug:

- When you have a useEffect function that references a state, props, or context values, add them to your dependency list. In other words, if you have a props called **trackId**, you would want to do something like this:

  ```
   useEffect(() => {
     trackId
   }, [trackId]);
  ```

Comment: You are writing "... just a nasty bug with useEffect()". Is this really a bug or works as designed? Will the react team change this behaviour in one of the next releases? Do you have an issue ticket for this?

Comment: @Paul, good point, I guess it works as designed, would you happen to have some documentation where it states this by the way? It would be helpful to many of us.

Answer (score -2):

I see a couple of potential issues, first of all you need to be calling `this.state` and `this.setState`. I'd guess state is undefined but this.state won't be. You also don't need to spread your state in your setState function, `this.setState({ test: 3});` is good enough, the setState function does this for you.

Secondly you need to update state for every change, it looks like you're only updating if the test value is 3, I'm surprised it's ever 3 with this implementation

Comment: its functional component so there will be no `this` to point.